# Upgrading from postgres 14 beta to postgres 14 new release

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, beta

I installed postgres 14 beta and i want to upgrade to 14 new release. I have just installed the new release pg 14 and when i try to start the pg 14 beta i get the error below. May i know the correct procedure of upgrading from beta to new release

```
-bash-4.2$ /usr/pgsql-14/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/14/data -l logfile start


waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.

-bash-4.2$ cat logfile
2021-10-27 13:19:29.507 UTC [5112] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2021-10-27 13:19:29.507 UTC [5112] DETAIL:  The database cluster was initialized with CATALOG_VERSION_NO 202106151, but the server was compiled with CATALOG_VERSION_NO 202107181.
2021-10-27 13:19:29.507 UTC [5112] HINT:  It looks like you need to initdb.
2021-10-27 13:19:29.507 UTC [5112] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: You need to use `pg_upgrade`.

Comment: Yes i can use upgrade, but what are the steps , do i have to install the new release first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been a change in the catalog version since v14 beta 1, so you have to use fump/restore of `pg_upgrade` to upgrade.

Install 14.0, create a new cluster and use the method of your choice to upgrade.

Comment: When i install 14.0 its overwriting /usr/pgsql-14/  which is used by 14 beta

Comment: You have to install it in a different path, so that you have both versions installed. At least if you want to use `pg_upgrade`. If you want to dump, you can do that with v14 beta 1, overwrite the binaries, create a new cluster and restore.